# SegmentedControl and Uipageview query

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uipageviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

[image]

How can i add sub options with segmented control like in the given Screen? 
Also i want to inquire about how can i add blurr effect to last/next page views just like the given screen. Thanks for your help